# ValueError: No loss found. You may have forgotten to provide a `loss` argument in the `compile()` method

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, loss

I have written the entire network of Dispnet using TensorFlow 1.2, and now I want to try the network in TensorFlow 2.10. So I wrote the following model based on the API of 2.12

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

layer = tf.keras.layers

conv1 = layer.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(7, 7), strides=(1, 1), padding="SAME", activation="relu, name="conv1")(input)

max_pool1 = layer.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding="SAME", name="max_pool1")(conv1)

......

layers...

......

cat1 = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=3)([upconv1, max_pool1])
iconv1 = layer.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(1, 1), padding="SAME", activation="relu", name="iconv1")(cat1)


model = keras.Model(inputs=input, outputs=iconv1, name="Dispnet_Simple")
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError, metrics=['accuracy'])
output = []

model.fit(x=combine_image, y=output, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, epochs=2)
```

errors:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    "C:\Users\SUPERJ~1\AppData\Local\Temp\__autograph_generated_filedo1_ym8c.py", line 15, in tf__train_function
    retval_ = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(step_function), (ag__.ld(self), ag__.ld(iterator)), None, fscope)
ValueError: in user code:

    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1160, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1146, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1135, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 995, in train_step
        self._validate_target_and_loss(y, loss)
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 959, in _validate_target_and_loss
        raise ValueError(


ValueError: No loss found. You may have forgotten to provide a `loss` argument in the `compile()` method.
```

I have changed the loss parameter of model. compile() countless times. How to resolve this?

Comment: I have solved this problem because the output in model. fit() is inconsistent with the actual output shape

I guess it's because the loss can't be backpropagated, so I reported this loss and couldn't find it

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please use the loss function in model.compile with '()' like - `loss=tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError()`.

Answer (score 0):

This problem arises as mentioned by @Superjiang because of inconsistency between the shape of input and output.

Solutions:

1. You could try to change the shapes of input and output arrays such that they are similar.
2. You could put a global average pooling layer and then change the dimensions.

Comment: Could also happen if your labels are completely missing for whatever reason.